# Change which SQL Server schema Laravel Passport uses

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

A colleague (recently left) has installed Laravel Passport on a site I'm now working on, which uses SQL Server, with the various oauth_ tables created in the default dbo schema.

However, our database has a number of schemas, depending on the purpose of the tables, including 'security' which has all the tables relating to auth stuff.

I've been asked to make changes so the tables are in security not dbo, but I can't figure out how to achieve this. In the passport model files there's just a table name specified, and the migrations generated also seem to have no option for specifying a schema. I couldn't see anything in the Passport docs to indicate whether it's possible either.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have passport use tables in the non-default schema?

Comment: Look at the end of this [thread](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/118) there is a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can configure different connections with differents schemas under your `database.php` config file and then specify `$connection` in your model, example:

```
    'sqlsrv1' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'schema'   => 'schema_name1',
    ],


    'sqlsrv2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'schema'   => 'schema_name2',
    ],
```

Then set the `$connection` property in desired model

```
 protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1';
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. I can't change the Passport model files of course, but I guess if I make the main connection default to the security schema, and the second connection default to dbo, and then in my abstract base model set the $connection there to the secondary, it should work.

Comment: Good luck! Tell us your results. And maybe you can overwrite (by publishing it before) the Passport model and do it more easy.

Answer (score 1):

this previous solution didn't work for me, this worked

I added `public` schema which is the default and `auth` that is the second schema
Laravel check and find a match and update or respond to your request.

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public,auth',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

on Migration, you can do something like this, adding `auth.` to tell where you want to add it

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('auth.users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            //...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('auth.users');
    }
};
```